# Can I return several lines using __str__?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there any method I can print two with using print(obj and obj = PhoneBook() one time?

```
class PhoneBook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contacts=[]
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.contacts[0]["name"]}'+'\noffice phone: '+f'{self.contacts[0]["phone"]}'+'\nemail address: '+f'{self.contacts[0]["email"]}\n\n'
        
    def add(self,name,office,email):
        d1 = {}
        d1['name']=name
        d1['phone'] = office
        d1['email'] = email
        self.contacts.append(d1)
    
obj = PhoneBook() # is there any way that I can print without rewrite again?
obj.add("Kim", office="1234567", email="kim@company.com")
print(obj)
obj = PhoneBook()
obj.add("Park", office="2345678", email="park@company.com")
print(obj)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.join()` for joining multiple strings together. For example:

```
class PhoneBook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contacts = []

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(
            "{name}\noffice phone: {phone}\nemail address: {email}\n".format(
                **contact
            )
            for contact in self.contacts
        )

    def add(self, name, office, email):
        d1 = {}
        d1["name"] = name
        d1["phone"] = office
        d1["email"] = email
        self.contacts.append(d1)


obj = PhoneBook()  # is there any way that I can print without rewrite again?
obj.add("Kim", office="1234567", email="kim@company.com")
print(obj)
obj = PhoneBook()
obj.add("Park", office="2345678", email="park@company.com")
print(obj)
```

Prints:

```
Kim
office phone: 1234567
email address: kim@company.com

Park
office phone: 2345678
email address: park@company.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, for starters you can change your `__str__` function to do what you did, BUT inside a loop.

```
def __str__(self):
    phonebook = ''
    for contact in self.contacts:
        phonebook += f'{contact["name"]}'+'\noffice phone: '+f'{contact["phone"]}'+'\nemail address: '+f'{contact["email"]}\n\n'
        
    return phonebook
```

This way,

```
obj = PhoneBook()
obj.add("Kim", office="1234567", email="kim@company.com")
obj.add("Park", office="2345678", email="park@company.com")

>>> print(obj)
    Kim
    office phone: 1234567
    email address: kim@company.com

    Park
    office phone: 2345678
    email address: park@company.com
```